# How to change id value when using Html.DropDownListFor helper in asp.net mvc 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial view that has something like this

```
 <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductName, Model.ProductList, "Select a Product") %>
```

Now you can create a new product and edit an existing product. Both editing and creating use the same form. The create is on the main page on load up. Edit pops up in a jQuery UI model dialog and renders a new partial view.

So as far as the page is concerned I have 2 dropdown boxes with the same "id" which is bad since they should be unique. So how do I change the id? So when the edit loads it might have a id of "editSelectedProductName"?

I tried to do this in the view model

```
public string SelectedProductName{ get; set; }

ViewModelConstructor()
{
  SelectedProductName = "EditSelectedProductName";
}
```

But it seems to not care and keeps using "SelectedProductName" as the product name

Comment: My tutorial blog show how to do this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx and http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I can't find the documentation at the moment, but there is an overload for DropDownListFor that will accept an object-typed collection of attributes (HtmlAttributes is the parameter name.)

It will look something like this:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SomeProperty, new {@id="UniqueID1234"});
```

You can use Intellisense to find the overload that includes HtmlAttributes.

Comment: I know it has the htmlAttributes property but in your example you hard-coded it. I can't hard-coded it since I am using the same partialview for both cases. Only way I can see is I have to make a special property in the view data model just to  hold the id. I was hoping I would not have to do that.

Comment: Another point to mention is the "name" attribute of that list will still be "SelectedProductName" even if you try to override it @name = "NotIdName" which kinda sucks but I don't think it should effect things( I at least hope not).

Comment: Dave, I cannot override the name attribute, do you know a way?

Comment: Never mind, I just found a way. Instead of "name", use "Name". Surprisingly works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hardcoded jQuery:

```
$('select#[id of your select box]').attr('id', '[id that you want]');
```

Comment: You shouldn't update the id client side, but server side instead