# How to override the name and id properties of a select dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do I override the id and name properties of an HTML select dropdown?

I have the following markup in my HTML to generate a select dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     m => m.CountryId,
     new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "Name", Model.CountryId),
     "-- Select --",
     new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

The output from the code above looks like this:

```
<select name="CountryId" id="CountryId" data-val-required="Country is required" data-val-number="The field CountryId must be a number." data-val="true" class="form-control">
     <option value="">-- Select --</option>
     <option value="1">Country 1</option>
     <option value="2">Country 2</option>
     <option value="3">Country 3</option>
     <option value="4">Country 4</option>
</select>
```

I see that it made both the name and id properties equal to CountryId.  I like more descriptive names for my markup, something like Countries.  And I also prefer to have my name and id properties to have the same description/name. So I tried the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     m => m.CountryId,
     new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "Name", Model.CountryId),
     "-- Select --",
     new { id = "Countries", name = "Countries", @class = "form-control" }
)
```

The output from the code above looks like this:

```
<select name="CountryId" id="Countries" data-val-required="Country is required" data-val-number="The field CountryId must be a number." data-val="true" class="form-control">
     <option value="">-- Select --</option>
     <option value="1">Country 1</option>
     <option value="2">Country 2</option>
     <option value="3">Country 3</option>
     <option value="4">Country 4</option>
</select>
```

Why was just the id property changed to Countries and name was left at CountryId?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor` is for the concept that your view model will also be used as form submit model, in that case you can consume the form post using your view model. In your case, if you simply want to customize form post variables, use `@Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(...), new { id = "id" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the case because the property needs to be capitalized (`Name`):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     m => m.CountryId,
     new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "Name", Model.CountryId),
     "-- Select --",
     new { id = "Countries", Name = "Countries", @class = "form-control" }
)
```

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2842359/1346943) to a similar question, with a reference to "Name" needing to be capitalized in the comments.

Comment: Good question, I don't have an explanation for it.